# Size of the local storage? - ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I was wondering what is the size of the local storage that your app can use. I know that the local storage depends on the browser and it is usually between 5 and 10 MB.

Is there other ways of storing the application data localy so that you can store more?

Comment: The most popular sqlite plugin for storing unlimited data is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the device **file system**:

- For the native access of the different file systems you can use the [cordova-file-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file).
- When you are using AngularJS in your application with **ngCordova** you can use [$cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).

For a more general overview, you may visit the cordova documentation for [Storage](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/storage/storage.html).